# Opening a link in a new tab by right clicking and selecting "Open link in new tab" is not working (Selenium)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm bringing up Amazon on Chrome, selecting Appliance, inputting "whirlpool" and then trying to right select and open "Whirlpool W10346771A Fresh Flow Produce Preserver")" in a new tab

```
              //| open | https://www.amazon.com/ | 
             driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.amazon.com/");

             // maximize window
             driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
             IWebElement ddSearch = driver.FindElement(By.Id("searchDropdownBox"));

            // 3 | select | id=searchDropdownBox | label=appliances
            var selectTest = new SelectElement(ddSearch);

             // Select a value from the dropdown                
            selectTest.SelectByText("Appliances");       

            // find the search textbox
            IWebElement txtSearch = driver.FindElement(By.Id("twotabsearchtextbox"));

            // enter "Whirlpool" search text and submit the page
            txtSearch.SendKeys("whirlpool");
            txtSearch.Submit();

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.LinkText("Whirlpool W10346771A Fresh Flow Produce Preserver")));
            IWebElement lnkWhirlpool = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Whirlpool W10346771A Fresh Flow Produce Preserver"));


            // right click on the link and open the link in a new tab
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.MoveToElement(lnkWhirlpool);
            actions.ContextClick(lnkWhirlpool).SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).SendKeys(Keys.Enter).Build().Perform();
```

How can I get the right click to "Open link in new tab"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use org.openqa.selenium.Keys and keyboard shortcut (CONTROL + SHIFT + click on element) to open the link in a new tab in the same browser window;

```
   WebElement lnkWhirlpool = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("linkText_to_target_element"));

   String keyPress = Keys.CONTROL.toString() + Keys.SHIFT.toString() + Keys.ENTER.toString();
   lnkWhirlpool.sendKeys(keyPress);
```

Check Keys documentation [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html)

Check [this](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.openqa.selenium.Keys/toString) tutorial for more examples of using shortcut keys;

Comment: Thank you that worked to open the link in a new tab, but it didn't show the right click and the choice being made. How can I do that?